# Concatenating two columns and having only one carriage return

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to concatenate two columns into one and managed to do it. But I dont want a carriage return for two columns, instead want only one with a space between two columns.

```
SELECT t1.save_line || t2.save_line as save_line 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM save_output_table 
    WHERE save_type = 'R' and seq_id = '0' and execution_id = '292' 
) t1 
    JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM save_output_table 
        WHERE save_type = 'R' and seq_id = '0' and execution_id = '286'
) t2 ON t1.line_id = t2.line_id
```

Output:

```
+------------+
| Save_line  |
+------------+
| 18         |
| 12         |
|------------|
| 23         |
| 22         |
+------------+
```

Expected:

```
+------------+
| Save_line  |
+------------+
| 18 12      |
| 23 22      |
+------------+
```

Comment: Can you add data of `save_output_table`? I am pretty sure that problem is not concatenation, but in join. Any way, you can use `CONCAT_WS(' ', t1.save_line, t2.save_line)`

Comment: The problem is in the data.  What's the point in storing the line endings?  Change how the data are loaded, so you don't have putz with CR LF in SQL.  You always add newlines as appropriate with printf later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the query is more simply written as:

```
SELECT (sov.save_line || sov2.save_line) as save_line
FROM save_output_table sov JOIN 
     save_output_table sov2
     on sov.line_id = sov2.line_id
WHERE sov.save_type = 'R' and sov.seq_id = '0' and sov.execution_id = '292' and
      sov2.save_type = 'R' and sov2.seq_id = '0' and sov2.execution_id = '286' ;
```

Then, you can replace the newline character with a space.  This might depend on your operating system, but something like this:

```
SELECT replace(sov.save_line || sov2.save_line0, char(13), ' ') as save_line
```

In Windows, you may need to replace both CR and LF:

```
SELECT replace(replace(sov.save_line || sov2.save_line0, char(13), ' '), char(10), '') as save_line
```

Comment: I am running it on windows and dint quite work as expected. Result is same as before.

Comment: @Goutam Show the actual output from the `sqlite3` command-line shell.